# ReplaceWith on hidden elements then showing in orginal positions, not in the position of their target

Tags: jquery, positioning, show, replacewith

Link:  http://jsfiddle.net/7GGeX/24/

Click on the links in 1,2,3 order and you'll see why I'm confused.

Does using a function inside replaceWith negate the positioning of the replacement?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".click1").click(function () {
        $("#one").replaceWith(function () {
            $('#replace1').show();
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `return` the value you want to use as the replacement.

```
$("#two").replaceWith(function() {
      // return the element
    return $('#replace2').show();
});
```

or don't pass a function:

```
$("#two").replaceWith($('#replace2').show());
```

Since you weren't returning anything explicitly, the `replace` div was being shown, then `undefined` was returned, effectively replacing the original with nothing.